# Firestore 1 global index vs 1 index per query what is better?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on my app and I just ran into a dilemma regarding what's the best way to handle indexes for firestore.

I have a query that search for publication in a specify `community` that contains at least one of the `tag` and in a geohash range. The index for that query looks like this:

```
    community Ascending tag Ascending location.geohash Ascending
```

Now if my user doesnt need to filter by `tag`, I run the query without the `arrayContains(tag)` which prompt me to create another index:

```
community Ascending location.geohash Ascending
```

My question is, is it better to create that second index or, to just use the first one and specifying all possible tags in arrayContains in the query if the user want no filters on tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is pertinently better, but it's a typical space vs time tradeoff.

Adding the extra tags in the query adds some overhead there, but it saves you the (storage) cost for the additional index. So you're trading some small amount of runtime performance for a small amount of space/cost savings.

One thing to check is whether the query *with* tags can actually run on just the second index, as Firestore may be able to do a zigzag merge join. In that case you could only keep the second, smaller index and save the runtime performance of adding additional clauses, but then get a (similarly small) performance difference on the query where you *do* specify one or more tags.